# Linking HTML to a combination of dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface

I have written a code to take values from two dropdowns, now I want to navigate to different URLs by taking combination of dropdown.

```js
(function() {
  $(".go-btn").on(
    'click',
    function(e) {
      // within this function you should figure out the url
      // to redirect to, depending on the selected values
      // the next line only shows the text of selected values
      $('#selected').html([$('#select1 option:selected').text(),
        $('#select2 option:selected').text()
      ].join('/'));
    });

}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="selCont">

  <h2>pick an option</h2>

  <select id="select1">
    <option value="1" selected>West</option>
    <option value="2">East</option>
    <option value="3">North</option>
    <option value="4">South</option>
  </select>

  <select id="select2">
    <option value="1" selected>Winter</option>
    <option value="2">Spring</option>
    <option value="3">Summer</option>
    <option value="4">Fall</option>
  </select>

  <button class="go-btn" type="submit">Go</button>

</div>
<div id="selected"></div>
```

**example:**

> west + winter to google.com
>
> east + spring to facebook.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a javascript switch.
EDITED

To start with i changed the onClick event to an onClick on the button.
I tested it in safari with Dreamweaver preview.

---

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="selCont">

  <h2>pick an option</h2>

  <select id="select1">
    <option value="1" selected>West</option>
    <option value="2">East</option>
    <option value="3">North</option>
    <option value="4">South</option>
  </select>

  <select id="select2">
    <option value="1" selected>Winter</option>
    <option value="2">Spring</option>
    <option value="3">Summer</option>
    <option value="4">Fall</option>
  </select>

  <button class="go-btn" onClick="run()" type="submit">Go</button>
```

---

Then I threw in an alert to check what happened. delete it afterwards.

---

```
function run(){
var value1 = $('#select1 option:selected').text();
var value2 = $('#select2 option:selected').text();
var valuecombo = value1 + "/" + value2;

switch (valuecombo) {
        default:
       //in case no matches are found this is what should happen. Could be an alert
//WINTER
    case 'West/Winter':

        alert("West/Winter will push you to google.com");
       window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
       break;

    case 'East/Winter':

        alert("East/Winter will push you to google.com");
       window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
       break;

    case 'North/Winter':

        alert("North/Winter will push you to google.com");
       window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
       break;

    case 'South/Winter':

        alert("South/Winter will push you to google.com");
       window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
        break;

//SPRING
    case 'West/Spring':

        alert("West/Spring will push you to google.com");
       window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
       break;

    case 'East/Spring':
        alert("East/Spring will push you to facebook.com");
       window.location.href = 'http://www.facebook.com';
       break;

    case 'North/Spring':

        alert("North/Spring will push you to google.com");
       window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
       break;

    case 'South/Spring':

        alert("South/Spring will push you to google.com");
       window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
        break;

//SUMMER
    case 'West/Summer':

        alert("West/Summer will push you to google.com");
       window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
       break;

    case 'East/Summer':

        alert("East/Summer will push you to google.com");
       window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
       break;

    case 'North/Summer':

        alert("North/Summer will push you to google.com");
       window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
       break;

    case 'South/Summer':

        alert("South/Summer will push you to google.com");
       window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
        break;

//FALL
    case 'West/Fall':

        alert("West/Fall will push you to google.com");
       window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
       break;

    case 'East/Fall':

        alert("East/Fall will push you to google.com");
       window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
       break;

    case 'North/Fall':

        alert("North/Fall will push you to google.com");
       window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
       break;

    case 'South/Fall':

        alert("South/Fall will push you to google.com");
       window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
        break;

//everything else

    }

};
```

Comment: can you please elaborate the code, i tried but its not working.

Comment: it seems there is some error, it is not working... may be some issue with brackets.

Comment: Try this now. I changed the onClick event to an **onClick="run()"** function on the button

Comment: IF you copy the entire code and paste it in your page, it should work straight away.

Comment: I am not getting any error but its not working, can you make it on jsfiddle or like the way i have posted the question so that i can run the code snippet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179448/discussion-between-jayant-kaushik-and-sparky).

Comment: no, may be it happened because i marked the below also, i have marked yours again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add conditions inside `function(e)` where you will if selected options are matching with your pattern if yes then open relevant link.

JSFIDDLE working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/vkt26hn1/

Below is complete code of your function:

```
 (function() {
      $(".go-btn").on(
        'click',
        function(e) {

          let match1 = "west + winter";
          let match2 = "east + spring";

          let value = $('#select1 option:selected').text() + " + " + $('#select2 option:selected').text()

          let url = "";
          if (value.toLowerCase() === match1) {
            url = "http://google.com";
          } else if (value.toLowerCase() === match2) {
            url = "http://facebook.com";

          }
          window.open(url, '_blank');
        });

    }());
```

Comment: can you please help me by writing for one so that i try for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a obj to hold your combinations and point to a URL.
Then you get the selected value, concatenate and check if is a valid combination.
This way you only need to update the `urls` when your code needs to change.

```js
(function() {
  var $sel1 = $('#select1');
  var $sel2 = $('#select2');
  var urls = {
    "1-1": "http://www.google.com",
    "1-2": "http://www.google.com",
    "1-3": "http://www.facebook.com",
    "1-4": "http://www.facebook.com"
    // "2-1", "2-2"... and go on
  };
  $(".go-btn").on(
    'click',
    function(e) {
      var key = $sel1.val() + '-' + $sel2.val();
      var value = urls[key] || 'Default value';
      $('#selected').html(`urls[${key}] = ${value}`);
    });
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="selCont">

  <h2>pick an option</h2>

  <select id="select1">
    <option value="1" selected>West</option>
    <option value="2">East</option>
    <option value="3">North</option>
    <option value="4">South</option>
  </select>

  <select id="select2">
    <option value="1" selected>Winter</option>
    <option value="2">Spring</option>
    <option value="3">Summer</option>
    <option value="4">Fall</option>
  </select>

  <button class="go-btn" type="submit">Go</button>

</div>
<div id="selected"></div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot,  can you let me know how to navigate to the URL instead of displaying it when we click Go.

Comment: Just use [`document.location.assign('new-url')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign) or `window.location.assign('new-url')`.